# Persistent cookie vs Temporary cookie

Tags: php, setcookie

I am new to php , I came across cookie and persistent cookie and i understand the difference between them.My question is that how can i make cookie persistent or temporary.I found only one syntax for cookies

```
 <?php
setcookie("user", "Alex Porter", time()+3600);
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Temporary cookies get deleted when you close the browser. No cookie is forever. "*If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).*"

Comment: @h2ooooooo my question is upper cookie is temporary or persistent

Comment: It's "persistent" because you specify an expire date.

Comment: then how to define temporary cookie

Comment: Read the manual: "*If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).*"

Comment: @h2ooooooo thanks but where can i find my cookie file in my harddisk

Comment: The location of the cookie file will vary depending on the browser that you're using; but most browsers provide a facility for examining cookies, so you shouldn't need to access a cookie file directly

Answer (score 1):

Phisically speaking, there is only one kind of cookie. You can make it persistent by choosing a large enough expiration time. If the expiration time is set to 0, the cookie will last only until your page is opened in the browser.

Your example cookie is persistent, it expires in one hour.

[Here](http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/cookies-the-same.html) is a link with a short explanation.

Most likely you can hardly access the phisical cookie on your hard disk, because borwsers store them in their internal logic. For example Firefox store cookies in a local SQLite database file in the browser's profile folder.

Comment: so above code will create file in my harddisk and what will be the path

Comment: Every cookie is stored on the hard disk, also session cookies.. But not surely in a "file", for example FF stores cookies in a local database file.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a cookie, 3rd argument (`time()+3600` in your example) specifies cookie's expiry date.

`time()+3600` means now+3600 seconds, which is 1 hour in the future. Time() function returns current time (unix time) in seconds.

There is no such thing as a really permanent cookie, more like expiring far in the future cookie.